# Nodejs download multiple files

Tags: node.js, image, download

I need to download ~26k images. The images list and urls are stored in csv file. Im reading the csv file and trying to download the images while looping through the list.

If im using small set ~1-2k it works fine but when i switch to the full set im getting EMFILE error.

```
Error: EMFILE, open 'S:\images_download\Images\189900008.jpg'
```

I've noticed that node tries to create all the files at once and this might be the issue but i'm unable to force it to create it one by one. My understanding is the code below should work like this but obviously is not.

(Just to mention that this code is executed on Windows)

Code:

```
var csv     = require("fast-csv");
var fs      = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var async   = require('async');

fs.writeFile('errors.txt', '', function(){})

var downloaded = 0;
var totalImages = 0;
var files = [];

csv
 .fromPath("Device_Images_List.csv")
 .on("data", function(data){
    files.push({device: data[0], url: data[1]})
 })
 .on("end", function(){     
    totalImages = files.length;

    async.each(files, function(file, callback) {
        var deviceId = file.device;
        var deviceUrl = file.url;   

        if ( deviceId != 'DEVICE_TYPE_KEY' ) {
                try {
                    writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('./Images/' + deviceId + '.jpg');
                    proxiedRequest = request.defaults({proxy: "http://proxy:8080"});
                    proxiedRequest(deviceUrl).pipe(writeStream); 
                    writeStream.on('open', function(fd) {

                        var rem = proxiedRequest.get(deviceUrl);

                        rem.on('data', function(chunk) {        
                            writeStream.write(chunk);       
                        });
                        rem.on('end', function() {
                            downloaded++;
                            console.log('Downloaded: ' + deviceId + '; ' + (downloaded + 1) + ' of ' + totalImages);
                            writeStream.end();                      
                        });

                    });

                    writeStream.on('close', function(){
                        callback();
                    });

                } catch (ex) {
                    fs.appendFile('errors.txt', deviceId + ' failed to download', function (err) {
                        callback();
                    });
                }
        }       
    }, function(err){
        if( err ) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {

        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: To make async process the items one at a time use `.eachSeries()` instead of `.each()`

Comment: You can also use `.eachLimit()` to process the files two at a time, three at a time etc..

Comment: Thanks @slebetman ! I've missed this bit. Works as expected!

Answer (score 3):

As @slebetman commented the issue can be solved by using [async.eachSeries](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachSeries) to process the files one by one or [async.eachLimit](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachLimit) to limit the parallel nodes:

```
async.eachLimit(files, 5, function(file, callback) {
 // ... Process 5 files at the same time
}, function(err){
});
```

Comment: It's better to write out the full relevant info because comments in SO are not meant to be permanent and can be deleted any time. The majority of comments aren't deleted but it should be noted that reviewers can and have deleted comments in the past to "clean up" the site. Comments are not meant to be content.